# An explicit description of $A_X$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective curve of genus at least $2$ and $p\in X$. Define $$A_X=H^0(X-p,\mathcal O_X).$$
By choosing a local parameter $z$ near $p$ we can see $A_X\subset Frac(\hat{O}_{X,p})=K\cong \mathbb C((z))$.

> Is there any explicit description of $A_X$ inside $K$? I mean given $f\in K$, what conditions are required on $f$ so that it is in $A_X$?
>
> Are the only units of this ring are the non vanishing constants?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean. Is $\mathcal{O}_X$ the sheaf of regular or holomorphic functions? If it's the first, then do you want $\hat O_{X,p}$ above or....? If its the second, then you can have essential singularities...

Comment: I mean the first and that's just an errata!

Comment: Are the only units of this ring are the non vanishing constants?

Comment: Yes. The divisor of a meromorphic function has degree zero. If $f\in A_X$ is a unit, it has no zero in $X-p$, hence its divisor is $0$ and $f$ is constant.